# This page can't be displayed in IE11

Tags: javascript, url, hyperlink

Whenever I am using IE-11 , and trying to open Hyperlink's I am getting this error.

I know this is IE-11 issue - which is faced by many users - 
but curious if there is any settings/workaround in Salesforce for this.

URL in IE :

> javascript:srcUp('https%3A%2F%2Fab--DEV.cs15.my.salesforce.com%2Fa3ke0000000CfNTAA0%3Fisdtp%3Dvw');

URL in Chrome : (THIS WORKS JUST FINE)

> https://ab--dev.cs15.my.salesforce.com/a3ke00000008bVy

**Edited :** 
This is code which I used for Hyperlink

```
<apex:outputtext ><apex:outputLink target="_newTab" value="/{!MyVar.Id}">{!MyVar.Name}</apex:outputLink></apex:outputtext>
```

Is there any workaround for this ?

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Lobby to ban the use of IE in your company. I know this sounds like a stupid comment, but seriously, the time you have to invest to support IE just isn't worth it if you have some control over the browsers people use.

Comment: I suppose I should try to be a bit more helpful. What are code are you using to display the URL?

Comment: @Poet - That's Funny and TRUE. But cant help it. Will see if its happening with all hyperlinks, if not will provide with code used for URL's

Comment: @Poet - Please see updated question

Comment: When you hover over the link in IE, at the bottom left does it show `javascript:srcUp('https%3A%2F%2Fab--DEV.cs15.my.salesforce.com%2Fa3ke0000000CfNTAA0%3Fisdtp%3Dvw');` or `https://ab--dev.cs15.my.salesforce.com/a3ke00000008bVy`. Going guess the former?

Comment: it shows this one
 __https://ab--dev.cs15.my.salesforce.com/a3ke00000008bVy

Comment: But when you click the link it shows `javascript:srcUp('https%3A%2F%2Fab--DEV.cs15.my.salesforce.com%2Fa3ke0000000CfN‌​TAA0%3Fisdtp%3Dvw');` in the URL?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35301/discussion-between-nilesh-mendhe-and-poet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what it looks like IE is doing is encoding the JS String as a URI Component, rather than just displaying the literal String. You can actually test this [here][1] by using the URI Encode/Decode functions.

As we discussed in chat, changing it so that rather than using an `<apex:outputLink>`, just using `<a href="/{!MyVar.Id}">My Link</a>` will avoid this error.

This is probably caused by the way `<apex:outputLink>` is rendered on the page.